# Are there any rules for giving bhiksha (alms) according to the shastras?

Tags: temple, customs

I've heard that there is eligibility and rules for engaging in bhikshadana but are there any rules to giving bhiksha as well?

We see people begging around temples in India, both ordinary people and people who 'look like' sadhus.  I have seen some of them curse if we don't give them alms and people give them something to avoid 'getting the curse'.